# Why is the COM interface contract immutable?

Tags: c++, com

I've googled quite a bit, and found it weird that no one cared to explain why COM interfaces are immutable. I suppose that the reason you're unable to remove any methods from a COM interface, is because a client relying on that interface, would encounter an error, which isn't good. But why would adding new features to the interface change any of that? Has this something to do with the underlying vtable?

Comment: A contract is a contract, is a contract ....

Comment: Sure, but how does adding a new method to the interface break a client using the COM component?

Comment: You have to provide an additional interface. A COM contract is fixed, and can't be extended, without breaking your clients. It's the nature of the IDL compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a method, a newer client that uses that method will fail when working with an older version of the component.

Older versions of the component won't have the new method unless you specifically add code to implement it, rebuild the component, and then reinstall the component on all machines that use the component.

If a newer version of the client attempts to call the new method on an older version of the component that doesn't have the method, undefined behavior will occur (likely a crash but silent data corruption is also possible). The new client will be attempting to call a method through a pointer entry in the vtable that did not exist when the old client was built so the old client will have some unrelated value in this location.

Of course, this wouldn't be an issue for you if you control both client and component and deploy them together but COM is designed for a much broader range of use cases than that.

Comment: Wouldn't the "older version of the component", by the very nature of interfaces, have implemented the methods? Or is it if we have some COM still running, which hasn't been restarted since the update of the interface, and thus lacking the methods?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted my answer. It is the correct answer to the question asked in the body of the question.

Comment: @Amnestic eh? If I make a DLL using your interface, and then you update your interface, then my DLL doesn't magically update to implement the new function!  Code attempting to call the new function will just read whatever junk is in memory after the end of my vtable, since my vtable is shorter than the "new" interface specification demands.

Comment: @DavidAnderson some people don't like one-sentence answers; perhaps you could elaborate with some more specifics.

Comment: I dont know why it was so hard for me to grasp, obviously we can have a client using a older COM with a newer interface. Just me being an idiot.

Answer (score 5):

COM has a very strong DLL Hell problem.  Several basic reasons:

- The programmers involved with writing the server and the client code rarely know each other, don't work together and have their own release schedules.
- Registering servers is by default machine-wide, affecting every single client program that depends on the server.  Isolated COM with a reg-free manifest is a workaround.
- Early-bound COM (using a v-table) is very efficient but extremely intolerant to v-table changes.  Mismatches are very hard to diagnose when the client code simply calls the completely wrong function or passes the wrong arguments.  Late-bound calls through IDispatch is a workaround but slow.
- COM programmers are very strongly motivated to cheat, changing the interface {guids} causes pretty grumpy client programmers and awkward support calls.  Making an interface backwards compatible is relatively easy to do, making it forward compatible never works.  Only changing the interface guid is truly safe.
- Deployment of COM servers is often a client duty, they typically don't know enough about the server to troubleshoot and correct problems.

These are otherwise generic versioning problems, many runtime implementations suffer from them with various amounts of pain.  A specific advantage in COM is that you can do something about it.  Change the {guids} and a lot of the nastiness evaporates.

Comment: "Change the {guids} and a lot of the nastiness evaporates". I agree. I've found you can make the COM contract interface mutable by templatizing the C++ interface classes. All I do now is change my IID_T, CLSID_T and LIBID_T GUID template parameters and add or change any code I want to which differentiates my related projects. Not only did I obtain the ability to change the GUIDs easily, but I get the benefits of templatized code reuse. What you get is the ability to let interfaces migrate in different directions without tripping up previously published editions.