# How are COM "rules" enforced?

Tags: com, versioning, dcom

When using COM (Component Object Model), [I've](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809984.aspx) [read](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/com/) that interfaces are immutable, and that new versions of interfaces have explicitly different names instead of just changing the behavior of an existing interface. For example, `ICollection`'s new version would be `ICollection2` or `ICollectionEx`, though the latter is not recommended (totally understandable).

I see there being a huge amount of value to gain in this approach in backwards-compatibility at the cost of aesthetics (which is quite petty in the grand scheme). Is this immutable interface idea enforced, and if so, how, and are there other systems that take this approach?

Comment: The rules are "enforced" by the fact that something is likely to crash and burn when you violate them. Code that breaks backward compatibility is backward-incompatible, essentially.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the COM interface contract immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056322/why-is-the-com-interface-contract-immutable) The immutability is enforced by convention. (COM does not have infinite knowledge. It doesn't know that the interface you're defining today is a modification of the interface you defined yesterday.)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Fair enough.

Comment: @RaymondChen OK. I wasn't sure if there was some global registry that somehow enforced it. I've never done COM programming, but the idea sounds good, but I know why many would not want to follow it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that it is not "enforced'"--except in rare cases where some special ops guys in black helicopters show up in the middle of the night and rendition you to Redmond.

I've seen it not followed and nothing breaks.  I would not swear on it, but if you compare typelibs from Microsoft Office applications, I would say they are more practical than idealistic (shhh.... sometimes the interfaces might change).

In practice, if you always add functions to the end of interfaces, you can cheat your way to not having to recreate interfaces.  The big problem is not having a customer use new versions of your program, but having customers using older versions than what they compiled against.