# Application.ShowWindowsInTaskbar gives `Runtime error 4609 String too long` in Word 365. Is it deprecated?

Tags: vba, ms-word

One of my customers reported `Runtime error 4609 String too long`. Debugging showed the failing statement to be `Application.showWindowsInTaskbar = True`. She is running Office 365
Investigating this I have found that `showWindowsInTaskbar` no longer appears in the Object model at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application

Is there a list of deprecated VBA features for this version of Office?

Comment: They [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29056322/11683) really change a COM interface. The method is probably there, but hidden. The only deprecation notice I can find is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.showwindowsintaskbar?view=word-pia, which is not a helpful place.

Comment: The quick way to check if a method is deprecated is to right click on the statement and select "Definition" from the context menu. If you get a message in the Object Browser that says "Cannot jump to 'MethodName' because it is hidden" you know that it has been deprecated. That doesn't necessarily mean that the method **can't** be used, but it is a strong indication that Microsoft may drop support for it in the future.

Comment: If that's the case, the error message is very misleading!

Comment: Re Kostas K's comment: I suspect the 4609 is a side effect in my customer's particular Word environment. I cannot reproduce it, either in Word 2013 or 365.

Comment: Re Timothy Rylatt;s comment, doing this in Word 2013 reveals deprecation there too.

Comment: Oh for the old days of well-documented maintenance levels released early to MSDN subscribers! Deprecations and enhancements were always documented as far as I remember.

Comment: If is Office 2013 where the property was hidden. It is non-hidden in Office 2010. It should not give that error though, it should silently not do anything, like any good "removed" property. You can file a bug... if you are able to find [where](https://superuser.com/q/333842/52365) to do so.